# Private DNS - Global Resolution

Tags: dns, ubuntu-server

I understand that it's a reasonably simple matter to place Bind9 on one of my servers and use that to resolve requests for subdomains on my network.

However, is it possible to install Bind9 on one of my servers and then use it to resolve the greater internet at large? I do understand that it will have to query up the DNS chain to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's how public and ISP-provided resolvers already work. (Although some are perhaps more likely to be running Unbound or PowerDNS instead of Bind9.)

There is no querying "up" the DNS chain in this situation. If you don't configure any upstreams (forwarders), Bind9 will start directly at the root zone (using its built-in list of [root servers](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers)) and will itself do the chasing of referrals/delegations (NS records).